# Vimtex citation movement bindings

Tags: plugin-vimtex

By default `<c-x><c-o>` opens all citations/references in `vimtex`, then pressing `tab` goes over all citations/references backwards. How do I set plugins that make `tab` go forward? I tried but couldn't find.

This is what `:verbose imap <tab>` says

```
s  <Tab>       * <Esc>:call UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()<CR>
    Last set from ~/.vim/plugged/ultisnips/autoload/UltiSnips/map_keys.vim line 62
```

Comment: That's quite possibly not a Vimtex feature but an integration with another autocomplete plug-in... What does `:verbose imap <Tab>` show you? Please [edit] the question to include that information. Any relevant snippet from your vimrc that might be useful too. Thanks!

Comment: @filbranden Added that info.

Comment: Turns out the behaviour is from [`supertab`](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab). Got it now. Thanks!

Comment: If you found the answer for your question, please post a self-answer. Thanks! (BTW, some plug-ins allow you to configure the direction in which they go through the list, it's possible that Supertab also allows that.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After suggestion from a comment I checked if this behaviour was from the autocomplete plugin [`supertab`](https://github.com/ervandew/supertab) that I've installed, and sure enough it was. So to change the direction I added the following to my `.vimrc` which makes `<Tab>` go forward:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-n>"
```